# New row in ASP.NET GridView Control

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to do something really simple, I just can't seem to find the EnableClientAddRow property, so I can set it to true.  I have a standard GridView control on a web form.  I want a button to appear on the web form.  When the user clicks the button, an empty row is added to the GridView UI, so the user can enter data in the appropriate fields.  The row will of course, have a "Save" button of some type in one of the columns.

I know this functionality must be in the GridView somewhere, I just can't find it.  I did find some odd hacks that try to manually implement this.  I'm not really interested in footer manipulations or binding tricks, just the standard add row method.

EDIT:
It appears the GridView does not support adding a row as a first-order operation.  This appears to be a serious design flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically add a new record to the underlying data source as a part of the "add record" button click action. I then re-bind the view in order to show the blank row.

The new record is typically a DataRow if the GridView is bound to a DataTable, or an object if the GridView is bound to a collection of a particular type. Not sure if that is what you  consider a binding trick from your question, but it works well and is quite easy to implement.

Edit - more detail to describe the process:
Add the row to the data source,  set the EditItemIndex to the newly added row in order for the row to enter edit mode, then bind the data source to the GridView. Your EditItemTemplate would contain a Cancel and a Save button. Cancel would re-bind the GridView to the underlying data source without the empty row and set EditItemIndex to -1, thereby removing the row from the GridView.

Comment: This sounds like it might work, however I think a little more detail would be helpful.  Is simply adding an empty row to the data source going to display an editable row with an add button?

Comment: Revised with more detail, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: So with this additional info, I've found this to be a more effective hack for the deficiencies in the GridView.  Thanks for taking the time to expand your answer, it really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

[How to easily insert row in GridView with SqlDataSource](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-insert-row-in-GridView-with-SqlDataSource.aspx)

Comment: This looks like it will work, however I consider this a hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new row to the datasource, even if the row has empty values, and you databind the datasource to the Gridview, it should show up as an editable row just like any of the other rows.