# Adding new row to ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem. I cannot find any option to add new row to gridview, only to delete, select or edit.

Google throws out alot of examples, but all examples end up with same error for me:

> Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove
>   one definition.

Since I have GridView populated from database on PageLoad, there is already DataSource bind to it (SQLDataSource).

If I try to add new row according to this tut: 
      http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/gridview-footertemplate.html
or this:
      http://matifnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/05/adding-dynamic-rows-in-aspnet-gridview.html
or this:
    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET

I get error, since all tutorials use empty gridView, without any data on startup.

This user here asked the same question: [New row in ASP.NET GridView Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642426/new-row-in-asp-net-gridview-control) but the last link, which looks promising, is no longer valid.. Shan's answer looks good too, but its not enough for me :(

Comment: where's your code showing what your doing?

Comment: Since I'm using same code as in linked tutorials, I think duplicating the code wont help. But I can copy and paste it from tutorials if you think that would help. Problem is: their code is working fine, so I'm not trying to fix their code. Problem is, that I'm using DataSourceID when I design the GridView and then try to use DataSource when page is running.

Comment: @SubjectX If you are then why error ? Look it will be better if all the elements related to this context are available here, rather than going to four tutorials guessing which one you implemented and where it went wrong , It's better if we can see what your problem.It's going to help you afterall and it will be easy for people to find real issue .

Comment: @SubjectX, anyone wishing to help you has to trawl though the tutorial looking for the bit your having problems with. This also limits the usefulness of this question going forward. Questions concerning code should always include the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least hassle option for my problem I found is this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZIOI136IKY

In short: adding controls to footer of GridView, then adding background code:

```
protected void lbInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("tbName")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Description"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("tbdesc")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Location"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("tbLoc")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["URL"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("tbURL")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["EnteredUser"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("tbUser")).Text;

        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
```

and finally calling OnClick event in webpage:

```
<FooterTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton OnClick="lbInsert_Click" ID="lbInsert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton> 
</FooterTemplate>
```

For more info watch youtube video, guy explains it really good!

Answer (score 0):

It requires you to do exactly that. You seem to have set both the DataSourceID and DataSource properties on GridView1. Remove one of them. The DataSourceID tends to be set in declarative markup and the DataSource tends to be set in codebehind. Because you're using a SqlDataSource, remove any lines that explicitly set the DataSource property in codebehind.

```
// Create SQLDataSource.
SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
sqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource123";

//Bind SQLDataSource to GridView
    GridView1.DataSource = sqlDataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hmm, how would GridView and DB update then itself, if I remove GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind(); calls since new data is in dt?

Comment: @SubjectX A lot depend upon how you had implemented your `GridView`,as per you comment i think you can remove `DataSourceID` property in your aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have defined two `Datasource`  for your `GridView`

one in page source like

```
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource"
```

and another in codeBehind

```
GridView.DataSource= //Your Datasource
```

Use only one `DataSource` and follow tutorials again .

-hope it helps .

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use functionality of a GridView's Choose Data Source option directly on control?

Comment: @SubjectX Yes you can then you should use only that `DataSource` for your Gridview.